# Using React i18next do I have to use withTranslation?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am wondering something.

Say I have a component and I want to access the `t` value. Do I have to hook it to redux. Since to use `react-i18next` I am also using `i18next` can't I just do:

```
import i18next from 'i18next'

class Comp extends Component {
    render() {
      return <Text>{i18next.t('space')}</Text>
    }
}
```

Or what's the downside of doing this? It seems it still does my translation but there must be a downside? I'm guessing only if the locale changes it won't see the update? Anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hooks on React Component classes (at least without HOC).

Best thing you can do is to import `withTranslation` and export the class via this component.

What I mean:

```js
// Other imports
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
    //Code of your class
}

export default withTranslation()(ClassComponent);
```

Notice you should call `t` with `this.props.t` while rendering.